# How to call YII model from javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I use ckeditor as an inline editor and added a button to save the content using AJAX. Everything works if I link to a php file which does the job for me. Anyhow, I'm using YII and I want to do this save work in a controller or in a file that uses my app settings.

So in my javascript plugin I call:

```
$.post("index.php/pagina/update?id=1", {
                        dataType: "text json",
                        data : editor.getData(),
                        success : alert('Opgeslagen!'),
                    } );
```

In my paginaController in the actionUpdate I got:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $model->content = 'werkt';
        $model->save();
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd have to pass the url Yii style, so that it accepts a parameter that is called `id`.

```
var url = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl(array("pagina/update", "id" => $model->id)); ?>';

$.post(url , { // rest of code
```

Also, you could use a Yii ajax function here that looks something like this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
        'url'=>'js:url',
        'data'=> "js: info",
        'type'=>'post',
        'dataType'=>'json',
    )); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I found out that the plugin was saved in the cache and didn't got updated on refreshes. So it didn't point to the new URL i gave, so it didn't work...